# Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a contact form using laravel 5.4 and I added my server email details to the .env and the mail.php but I'm getting this error

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "421", with message "421 Unexpected failure, please try later
>   "

If I try this and I use mailtrap it works fine.

This is my mail.php

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@website.co.za'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Info'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

My .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=hosting.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@website.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Comment: If it's working with mailtrap, then what is the problem?

Comment: try check you username and password

Comment: If you've made changes to the env file recently try running `php artisan config:clear`. Also you should manually check if your mail login and server information works.

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya - The problem I'm having is that I'm getting the error that I've posted in my question and everything is correct

Comment: @hafiz - My username and password is correct

Comment: @Sandeesh - I've ran `php artisan config:clear` and I've even sent an email to the email I'm using and that works fine. But I'm still getting the error

Comment: @Shiva478 dig into the log file for more information regarding the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the config/mail.php

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', ''),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];
```

Make sure the .env file has the following

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=hosting website 
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Also clear the config cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```