# Unable to find the .env file in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

We use symfony and while resetting the password I am getting the below error 
"Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php".

I even tried finding the .env file but I could not.

Comment: You can reference [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150245/swift-transportexception-in-abstractsmtptransport-php-line-383-in-laravel) Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its suppose to be on the root directory, where is composer.json, config and src directories are.
If it not exist you can create it.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#the-env-file-environment-variables

If you created your application after November 15th 2018
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html#updating-my-application

Comment: This is really a stupid change.  In the cloud, best practice is to remove all .env files and configure the environment externally.  In an Azure Web App for example you use the App Config to set the environment variables.  So in my case Symfony is crashing in cloud because .env file not found.  So I have to put a stub .env file in the repository.  Ugh.

Comment: @AQuirky I can't agree more.